# Problem with creating truncated normal random variates

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, normal-distribution

python newbie here so apologies if this is a dumb question. I am trying to do something I imagine is simple. Create a range of values bounded by an upper and lower limit with a given mean and std_dev:

I am using the `scipy.stats.truncnorm`

```
r = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)
```

I imagine I am applying the wrong function because I have absolutely no idea how to interpret the values I am getting from the inputs I am providing

```
a (lower bound) = 20.9
b (upper bound) = 46.5
x_avg (mean) = 29.8
x_std (std_dev) = 4.5

size (# of values) = 20

r = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, x_avg, x_std, size)

array([123.98250345, 124.32804805, 123.98434454, 123.86675932,
       124.2113707 , 123.85307689, 124.06329418, 124.32192561,
       124.04215402, 124.00524577, 124.00042372, 123.87499012,
       124.13146939, 123.94714796, 124.13634181, 123.9475407 ,
       124.14616414, 123.85190967, 124.29072561, 124.02151428])
```

I would imagine I would get 20 values huddled around the mean I provided but instead they are all huddled around 123...Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments `a` and `b` aren't the bounds. From the docs:

```
a, b = (myclip_a - loc) / scale, (myclip_b - loc) / scale
```

So, following the docs notation:

```
myclip_a = 20.9
myclip_b = 46.5
loc = 29.8
scale = 4.5

a, b = (myclip_a - loc) / scale, (myclip_b - loc) / scale

truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc, scale, size=20)
```

gives

```
array([29.78710758, 29.61708513, 25.92957773, 39.12850079, 35.39048686,
       27.90837582, 31.68381045, 27.66714137, 23.968335  , 31.75038033,
       26.74734003, 33.02933497, 21.98563681, 31.95292654, 27.02312225,
       34.61312831, 22.8792215 , 34.76698613, 24.38504279, 24.28014787])
```

The docs could be a bit clearer - you have to go to the docstring for `truncnorm` to find that `a` and `b` are essentially Z-values, in normal distribution lingo.